# How to create a vector based on a sequence of data from another vector

Tags: r, vector

I want to create a vector of colors `data_pal` based on a vector of variables (from a dataframe `df$column`)using a custom palette (`test_pal`). I managed to work out a solution (below). It works but I believe it could be achieved much simpler and elegant.  Here I have a vactor of three variables (C, R, NR) and three colors. But for much more variables it will get too big.
Can anyone give me a solution (a failed with `match()`).

```
variables <- unique(df$column)#Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "C"<"R"<"NR": 2 3 1
test_pal <- brewer.pal(length(variables), "Accent")#vector of colors
names(test_pal) <- sort(variables)#assign variables' names to colors

i <- data_pal <- NULL

for(i in 1:length(df$column)) {
  data_pal <- c(data_pal, ifelse(df$column[i] == variables[1], test_pal[1],
                                 ifelse(df$column[i] == variables[2], test_pal[2],
                                        ifelse(df$column[i] == variables[3], test_pal[3],NA))))
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a set of inputs and corresponding expected outputs....and what do you mean by a failed with `match()`

Comment: I tired ```data_pal <- match(df$column, test_pal)```

Comment: @I_O it does not give what I want

Comment: this: `data_pal <- test_pal[d$column]`

Comment: @I_O that's the solution, many thanks!!!